# How to convert rows into columns in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, pivot

[image]

I want to convert this table to horizontal such that the column of code_val is horizontal

```
Null Half_day half_day Null Null Null
```

Like above.

Comment: Pivot is not supported in MySQL. Emulate (conditional aggregation or dynamic SQL).

Comment: WHat if there are more than 6 rows? how about 5?

Answer (score 0):

Pivoting and Unpivoting not supported in MySQL

What you can do?

```
select id,attendence_remark_code_val, 'a' col, a value
from attendance
union all
select id,attendence_remark_code_val, 'b' col, b value
from attendance
union all
select id,attendence_remark_code_val, 'c' col, c value
from attendance
```